# Confused with the Group By function in SQL

Tags: sql

**Q1**: After using the Group By function, why does it only output one row of each group at most? Does this mean that having is supposed to filter the group rather than filter the records in each group?

**Q2**: I want to find the records in each group whose ages are greater than the average age of that group. I tried the following, but it returns nothing. How should I fix this?

SELECT *, avg(age) FROM Mytable Group By country Having age > avg(age)

**Thanks!!!!**

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: **q1:** `group by` is an instruction that can summarise information and (by definition) it produces 1 row per unique combination of column values as specified by you in the `group by clause`.  **q1b**  `having` is to be used to filter on aggregated data whereas `where` cannot filter by aggregated data. **q2** you need more than 1 query to achieve comparison of a calculated average to the source data.

Comment: Are you still confused; none of the answer explained it?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the average age for each country in a subquery and join that to your table for filtering:

```
SELECT mt.*, MtAvg.AvgAge 
FROM Mytable mt

     inner join
     (
       select mtavgs.country
            , avg(mtavgs.age) as AvgAge 
       from Mytable mtavgs
       group by mtavgs.country
      ) MTAvg
      on mtavg.country=mt.country
        and mt.Age > mtavg.AvgAge
```

GROUP BY returns always 1 row per unique combination of values in the GROUP BY columns listed (provided that they are not removed by a HAVING clause). The subquery in our example (alias: MTAvg) will calculate a single row per country. We will use its results for filtering the main table rows by applying the condition in the INNER JOIN clause; we will also report that average by including the calculated average age.

Comment: Did it solve your problem? If I did, select this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY is a keyword that is called an aggregate function. Check this out here for further reading [SQL Group By tutorial](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-group-by/)

What it does is it lumps all the results together into one row. In your example it would lump all the results with the same country together.

Not quite sure what exactly your query needs to be to solve your exact problem. I would however look into what are called window functions in SQL. I believe what you first need to do is write a window function to find the average age in each group. Then you can write a query to return the results you need

Comment: It is more of a difficult problem to solve in just an SQL statement especially if you aren't too comfortable with SQL. What I might do if you have the option to use another language alongside is to run the query to find each of the average ages. Then write a query like SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE AGE > (pass in age parameter here)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your dbms type and version, you may be able to use a "window function" that will calculate the average per country and with this approach it makes the calculation available on every row. Once that data is present as a "derived table" you can simply use a where clause to filter for the ages that are greater then the calculated average per country.

```
SELECT mt.* 
FROM (
        SELECT *
            , avg(age) OVER(PARTITION BY country) AS AvgAge
        FROM Mytable
        ) mt
WHERE mt.Age > mt.AvgAge
```